# Spring injection list of beans with qualifier (intersecting lists)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I try to inject list of beans having partially matching collections. I looked through different Spring guides with collection injection and it doesn't help me.
I have the following situation:

```
abstract class A {
   public A(List<Processor> processors)
}

@Service
class B extends A {
   @Autowired
   public B(@Qualifier("basicProcessors") List<Processor> processors) {
       super(processors);
   }
}

@Service
class C extends A {
   @Autowired
   public C(@Qualifier("advancedProcessors") List<Processor> processors) {
       super(processors);
   }
}

@Configuration
class ProcessorsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public List<Processor> basicProcessors() {
        return Arrays.asList(new BasicProcessor());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public List<Processor> advancedProcessors() {
        return Arrays.asList(new BasicProcessor(), new AdvancedProcessor());
    }
}
```

I suppose that this approach should work but spring cannot find matching beans. I can't use strategy with configuration class including bean definition as single entities because advanced processors has intersection `BasicProcessor`.

Please, provide some ideas how to reach this goal. Any links, code snippets are welcome.

Comment: `baseProcessors` != `basicProcessors`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Good remark. It's misspelling. I'll fix it in question.

Comment: And even with that, how are you constructing those beans? There is no `@Component`, `@Autowired` is in the wrong place, please provide code that does actually match your code. Basically what you are trying should just work, also why not write a proper `@Qualifier` annotation put that on your processors and inject them based on that.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your attention. I try to provide minimum sample. But it looks like my mistake was with configuration `ProcessorsConfiguration` split on 2 different packages

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't get your proposal: " why not write a proper Qualifier annotation put that on your processors and inject them based on that." Could you provide a sample?

Comment: You can create an annotation that itself is annotated with `@Qualifier` you can then put those annotations on the `Processor` implementation (1 or more of those) and inject them based on the qualifier. You can then do something like `@AdvancedProcessor List<Processor> processors` without defining a specific bean for it.

Comment: @Ray, I don't think I understand the problem. I tried your code. The lists are getting injected as expected - "advanced" gives 2 items and "basic" 1, exactly as the bean configurations are returning.